# Raiz quadrada manualmente em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algoritmo, loop, matemática

Estou tentando calcular manualmente raiz quadrada em JavaScript.

Teoricamente era pra parar em 100 conforme o valor que está na variável numero, porém ele continua multiplicando.

Amostra do código:

```js
var numero = 100;
var contador = 0;
var i;
var num1 = 0;
var num2 = 0;
do {
for (i = 0; i < numero; i++) {
  contador++
  num1++
  num2++
  
  var multi = num1 * num2;
  var resultado = multi * multi / multi;
  console.log(multi);
} 
} while (resultado < 100) {

}


console.log(contador);
```

Comment: Coloca `var resultado` fora do `for` e só `resultado = ...` dentro.

Comment: Se é para ser "manualmente" não há por que utilizar javascript, basta papel e lápis.

Comment: Você está tentando fazer um `do{...}while(...);` ou um `while(...){...}`?

Comment: Manualmente no sentido de não usar math.sqrt() @anonimo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este código é complexo e confuso demais e isto dá margem para criar vários erros. Seu algoritmo não calcula a raiz quadrada de qualquer número, mas imagino que só deseja os que podem ser calculados como inteiros, pelo menos é o que indica o que já fez. Não é a forma mais otimizada de fazer isto mas é muito mais simples.

O que precisa fazer para achar a raiz quadrada inteira? Ir dividindo o número por um divisor, e aí vai subindo esse divisor até chegar no valor desejado, mas o novo divisor precisa a média do valor dividido e o próprio divisor, desta forma além de ser mais performático por evita muito número a tosa , mas consegue melhores aproximações. Este algoritmo pode não ser o mais preciso em todos cenários, mas aái depende do requisito, pelo menos ele funciona.

```js
var numero = 101;
var divisor = 1, dividido = 0;
for (var  i = 0; i < numero; i++) {
    dividido = numero / divisor;
    divisor = (dividido + divisor) / 2;
}
console.log(divisor);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/SquareRoot.js).

Usei 101 para mostrar que funciona com números quebrados. Seu algoritmo não funcionava.

Comment: Grato, mas estou com uma dúvida nesta parte: 
dividido = numero / divisor;

Se o numero é 100 e o divisor foi declarado como 1, como ele está se somando para a divisão?

Comment: E eu não entendi a dúvida.

Comment: Creio que não elaborei adequadamente. 
Dentro do for há o dividido = numero / divisor, eu entendi que o numero(foi declarado com 101) foi dividido pelo divisor(que foi declarado por 1)
logo 101/1 = 101, não compreendi esta parte.

Comment: Você tem que testar vários números, não? Tem que começar por algum. Poderia ter começado pelo 2, claro, eu não fiz otimizações, fui no primeiro caso a se testar.

Comment: Entendi melhor agora, de qualquer forma, obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Existe uma aproximação rápida de raiz quadrada através de uma [equação linear](https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-use-linear-approximation-to-the-square-root-function-to-estimate-squa-2):

```
L(x) = f(a) + f'(a)*(x-a)
```

Para um dado valor `a` em que a função tenha um valor conhecido e `f'(_)` sendo a derivada da função. Por coincidência, a derivada da raiz quadrada é a metade do inverso da raiz quadrada.

O valor da raiz quadrada é plenamente conhecida em quadrados perfeitos, logo, vamos tratar `a` como sendo um quadrado perfeito, e `f(a)` sua raiz inteira.

Logo, a fórmula da aproximação pode ser transformada assim:

```
                                    (x-a)
sqrt_approx(x) = sqrt_int(a) +  -------------
                                2*sqrt_int(a)
```

Para a aproximação dar certo, preciso escolher um `a` próximo o suficiente de `x`.

Assim, nosso algoritmo agora se resume a:

1. achar `a` quadrado perfeito (e sua raiz inteira `sqrt_int(a)`) o mais próximo de `x`
2. aplicar a fórmula

A grosso modo, seria isso:

```js
function sqrt_approx(x) {
  let sqrt_a = raiz_do_quadrado_mais_proximo(x);
  let a = sqrt_a * sqrt_a;

  // se x for um quadrado perfeito, x-a resultará em zero e a resposta será sqrt_a
  return sqrt_a + (x-a)/(2*sqrt_a);
}
```

Ótimo, agora só falta definir quem é o quadrado mais próximo de `x`. Como estamos lidando com números reais, não faz sentido investigar raízes de números negativos, logo vou reduzir o conjunto de busca apenas para os positivos. A ideia é bem simples: itero de 0 a infinito, verificando a distância do quadrado da variável de iteração para o `x`. No momento em que houver uma inflexão (ie, a distância deixar de ser negativa e passar a ser positiva), retorno ou o elemento atual da iteração ou o elemento anterior, de acordo com o quadrado mais próximo de `x`:

```js
function raiz_do_quadrado_mais_proximo(x) {
  let i = 0;
  while (true) {
    let ii = i * i;
    if (ii - x > 0) {
      let dist_ii = x - ii;
      let dist_ant = x - (i-1)*(i-1);
      if (dist_ii < 0) {
        dist_ii *= -1;
      }
      if (dist_ant < 0) {
        dist_ant *= -1;
      }

      return dist_ant < dist_ii? i-1: i;
    }
  }
}
```

O código acima pode ser otimizado trivialmente para:

```js
function raiz_do_quadrado_mais_proximo(x) {
  let i = 0;
  while (i*i < x) { // itera até a inflexão
    i++;
  }
  let dist_ii = i*i - x; // i*i >= x garantido, depois da inflexão, daí dist_ii está sendo calculado já positivo
  let dist_ant = x - (i-1)*(i-1); // antes da inflexão, x será maior que o quadrado, daí dist_ant está sendo calculado já positivo

  return dist_ant < dist_ii? i-1: i;
}
```

Juntando tudo, temos:

```js
function faz_leitura(form) {
  let x = Number(document.getElementById("quad").value);
  let raiz_apprx = sqrt_approx(x);
  let err = x - (raiz_apprx * raiz_apprx);
  if (err < 0) {
    err = -err;
  }
  
  document.write("<div>Raiz quadrada aproimada de " + x + " é " + raiz_apprx + ", com erro de " + err + "</div>");
}

function raiz_do_quadrado_mais_proximo(x) {
  let i = 0;
  while (i*i < x) {
    i++;
  }
  let dist_ii = i*i - x;
  let dist_ant = x - (i-1)*(i-1);

  return dist_ant < dist_ii? i-1: i;
}

function sqrt_approx(x) {
  let sqrt_a = raiz_do_quadrado_mais_proximo(x);
  let a = sqrt_a * sqrt_a;

  // se x for um quadrado perfeito, x-a resultará em zero e a resposta será sqrt_a
  return sqrt_a + (x-a)/(2*sqrt_a);
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="faz_leitura(this); return false;">
<div>
  <input required type="text" id="quad"/>
  <label>valor a ser calculada a raiz</label>
</div>

<button type="submit">SQRT</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dessa forma que fiz, você diminui o numero de variáveis do código e consegue ver os valores de multi e do contador no console:

```js
var numero = 100;   
var resultado = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < numero; i++) {
  var multi = i * i;
  resultado = multi * multi / multi;
  console.log(`${i}° de multi: ${multi}`);
} 

console.log("Valor do Contador: ", i);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Aqui eu executei e ele parou em 100 normalmente. Geralmente quando
>   estou com dúvida no tamanho do laço, eu coloco algum print contando
>   pra ver como esta funcionando:

```js
var numero = 100;
var contador = 0;
var i;
var num1 = 0;
var num2 = 0;
do {
for (i = 0; i < numero; i++) {
  contador++
  num1++
  num2++
  
  var multi = num1 * num2;
  var resultado = (multi * multi) / multi;
  console.log("contador:" + contador + " - resultado: " + resultado);
} 
} while (resultado < 100) {

}


console.log(contador);
```

Answer (score -1):

Se precisar, tenho uma função pra isso:

```
function calculoRaiz(numero) {

   var divisorRaiz = 1, calcDiv = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i <= numero; i++) {
       calcDiv = numero / divisorRaiz;
       divisorRaiz = (calcDiv + divisorRaiz) / 2;
   }
   return divisorRaiz;
}

calculoRaiz(100);
```